# Unexpected behavior after running python setup.py install inside virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py

Here's my directory structure for reference.

```
|- package1
|   '- abc.py
|- setup.py
|- examples
|   '- directory1
|         '- run.py
|- venv
```

After running `python setup.py install`, I see that a `package1.egg` file is placed successfully in `venv/lib/python*/site-packages`. When I run `pip list` the output contains the `package1` entry with the correct version as described in the `setup.py` file.

Now, when I try to run `python examples/directory1/run.py` the first line of which is `import package1`, I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package1'`. I get the same error when I launch the python interpreter and try to import `package1` too.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What does your `setup.py` look like? You also need `__init__.py`s in each package directory.

Comment: Gah! That was the reason. I did not have an `__init__.py` in my package directory. Thank you for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is - Create a black file called `__init__.py` in the package directory structure.